# Filtering a column of 'Factor' type in a dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have been using us-adult-income census 1994 [adult-data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data)  and I want to filter columns based on education.

I've tried:

```
subset(mydata,education == "HS-grad")
```

by keeping it as a facotr and converting it into character even

```
mydata$education <- as.character(mydata$education)
```

but they didn't work

structure of education colum in mydata:

```
$ education     : Factor w/ 16 levels " 10th"," 11th",..: 10 12 2 10 13 7 12 13 10 16 ...
```

Comment: Can you show the full output of `levels(mydata$education)`? I can't see anything obviously wrong with your `subset()` command, but there may be some issues caused by how the factor is set up.

Comment: "they didn't work" please be more specific; generally, consider using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` as you ingest the data to R, and examine the output of `unique(mydata$education)` carefully for whitespace

Comment: Code works fine in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried using the following way and code works just fine

```
data = read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data",
                  sep=",",header=F,col.names=c("age", "type_employer", "fnlwgt", "education", 
                                               "education_num","marital", "occupation", "relationship", "race","sex",
                                               "capital_gain", "capital_loss", "hr_per_week","country", "income"),
                  fill=FALSE,strip.white=T)


str(data)

data1 <- subset(data,education == "HS-grad")
```

Comment: I gave you a upvote :) however, I would use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, as it loads question marks in some of the columns. Handling it with as strings and as factor will make his life easier ;)

Comment: if you dont want string to be factor it is good to keep stringsAsFactor as False